# Can I make the QR codes appear in a 4 items row

Tags: reactjs

[image: This is how the qr codes are currently displayed]I am trying to make QR codes Sheet of printable size with React.

I am storing the QR codes generated in an array. Then using the map() function to extract the values.

```
    var value = [];

    var up = this.state.MonoQuantity;
    for (var i = 0; i < up; i++) {
      var rando = randomstring.generate(3);
      value.push(this.state.Lotno + i + rando + this.state.mReward);
    }
    return value;
  };

....

<>
  {this.generateMono().map(n => {
        return (
                <>
                  <tr key={n} style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
                    <QRCode value={n} size={70} level={"H"} />
                  </tr>
                  <tr style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>{n}</tr>
                </>
              );
            })}
</>
```

Comment: This is not a react problem, this is all about HTML & CSS. Using table rows is definitely not the correct way here. Did you consider using `<td>`?

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the right way to do it?

Comment: I tried <td> but how do I limit to 4 items.

Comment: Split items to groups by 4 first (resulting in a 2D array), then generate your UI from the groups. Anyway, you can just generate a flat list of items and use CSS to group them by 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<td>` to render in a row

give a try to this:

```
<tr>
{this.generateMono().map(n => {
        return (
                <>
                  <td key={n} style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
                    <QRCode value={n} size={70} level={"H"} />
                  </td>

                </>
              );
            })}
</tr>
```

To make chunk of elements with 4 element in each row you can do something like this working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bash-xxgfj

```
let i,
    j,
    arr,
    chunk = 4; // number of element required in each row
let chunkedData = [];

const data = this.generateMono();

for (i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
  arr = data.slice(i, i + chunk);

  chunkedElements.push(
      <tr>
        {arr.map(n => {
          return <td><QRCode value={n} size={70} level={'H'}/></td>;
        })}
      </tr>,
  );
}

render;
{
  return (
      <div className="App">

        {chunkedData}

      </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this Helps!! Happy coding

Comment: Sir, thanks to you I have got the QR codes in a row but can you please help me limiting to only four items in a row as I have a lot of codes in the array and now everything is coming in one row.

Comment: yes you can !! to do that you need  first make a chunk of array elements into 4 and then map over it and render a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>

{this.generateMono().map(n => {
        return (
                  <td key={n} style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
                    <QRCode value={n} size={70} level={"H"} />
                  </td>

              );
            })}
</tr>
```